# How do I exit the vi session which runs during Perl script execution?

Tags: perl, system, exec, vi, interactive

I have to run few jobs. After running each job, it runs  `vi` on the contents. After writing and quitting (usually I do `:wq!`) those data get updated in the database. As the number of these kind of jobs is more than a hundred, I thought of automating the process using Perl.

But when I ran the script, I got stuck in `vi`, unable to make it exit on its own. This requires manual intervention and fails the purpose of my script. I need help on how to handle such situation as it will help me to save time and effort.

Code is as given below:

```
print "Enter job name - \n";
$job_rc = <>;
print "Job entered by you is $job_rc \n";
my @job_name = ("job1", "job2", "job3", "job4");
my $total_job = @job_name;
print "Total job present = $total_job + 1 \n";
for ($i = 0; $i < $total_job; $i++) {
    print "Curent job name: $job_name[$i] \n";
    system "cr_job $job_name[$i] $job_rc";
    sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: Why are you opening the vi editor at all if it supposed to be done without human intervention? Knowing that, we can look at how to approach this problem.

Comment: "when I ran the script" -> How will we know what's wrong with it if we don't know what it is?

Comment: actually we are not opening the vi editor, the job automatically opens the vi editor in case if we need to edit any data (mainly the date need to update) which after saving load the same data to db table.. I am actually calling each job saved in an array and then running them one after another.

Comment: Have you tried piping the filehandles for the program to say, /dev/null ? cr_job $job_name[$i] $job_rc 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null

I'm guessing vi is "opening" for you because the ouput of the "cr_job" is telling your terminal to do so.

Comment: i checked it but it is bypassing the terminal, as a result the db is not getting updated. as i mentioned before also, once we close the terminal, it will update those data in DB and we can't modify the sequence as it was provided by client

Answer (score 1):

I think you approach the problem from the wrong side. Instead of exiting `vi`, think about not running it.

I can only guess why `vi` runs, it seems related to your “jobs”. One of the possible reasons is that they run a default text editor to grab some user input (well-known example of such behaviour is that when you call `hg commit`, `svn commit`, `cvs ci`, etc. without providing message, they automatically run a text editor to get the commit message).

If this is the case, first check your “jobs”, as they may have options to disable this very prompt. If not, they may be using the `$EDITOR` environment variable to decide which editor to run, setting this variable to something you prepare (for example, script which will write default message to file given as parameter) may do.

Comment: we are running the jobs that are given to us by the clients, which we can't modify. because of this there is no other way according to me other than exiting vi.